# WinAPI - button cannot be clicked

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I want to make a panel, which groups buttons by itself:

```
HWND my_panel = CreateWindow(
    "STATIC",
    "",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
    30,
    100,
    300,
    300,
    main_window, // main dialog
    NULL,
    ( HINSTANCE ) GetWindowLong( main_window, GWL_HINSTANCE ),
    NULL
);
```

Then I add a button to this panel:

```
HWND button_in_a_group = CreateWindow(
    "BUTTON",
    "Hello world",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
    20,
    20,
    50,
    50,
    my_panel, // as a child for above
    NULL,
    ( HINSTANCE ) GetWindowLong( main_window, GWL_HINSTANCE ),
    NULL
);
```

When I click the button, it doesn't send a `WM_COMMAND` but `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` to callback function. Then, if I press Enter, it works - `WM_COMMAND` is sent by the button.

How to enable mouse click on nested button, and why nested windows doesn't work as expected?

Comment: *to callback function* ? button send messages to parent window, not to some function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messages are sent to parent window. In this case the static windows is the button's parent. So the main window is not receiving button messages, except `WM_PARENTNOTIFY`.

You can subclass the static window:

```
SetWindowSubclass(my_panel, ChildProc, 0, 0);
```

Define a `ChildProc` to catch the button messages. See also [Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183(v=vs.85).aspx)

The button also requires an identifier as follows:

```
CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Hello world", ... my_panel, HMENU(BUTTON_ID) ...);
```

`WM_COMMAND` message is sent to `ChildProc` when button is clicked. The `BN_CLICKED` notification carries `BUTTON_ID`

Note, `SetWindowSubclass` needs additional header and library:

```
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib") //Visual Studio option for adding libraries
...
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR)
{
    switch(msg) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case BUTTON_ID:
            MessageBox(0, "hello world", 0, 0);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, ChildProc, 0);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: The STATIC control also needs the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` [extended window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) so that keyboard navigation works. Arguably a better solution would be to not introduce a child/parent relationship at all, and make the frame and buttons siblings. It's just a lot easier to manage, and doesn't change the perceived visual representation.

Comment: I tried `SetWindowLongPtr( my_panel, GWLP_WNDPROC, ( LONG_PTR ) DlgMain );` as the `SetWindowSubclass` didn't compile. It works - but now `my_panel` seems to be invisible. Did I miss something? `ShowWindow` takes no effect.

Comment: You probably missed the header and lib. See update answer.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Works perfect, but I had to `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` before `#include <windows.h>`. It is good to point out this requires version 5.81 or newer of ComCtl32.dll.

Comment: Yes, `0x0501` is for Windows XP, and ComCtl32.dll 5.81 was available that far back. It's reasonable to make that the minimum target.

Comment: Just for completeness, "old school" subclassing prior this `SetWindowSubclass` API was done with `GetWindowLong` to save the previous WndProc of the control, then `SetWindowLong` to replace the control's current window proc with a custom one. And in the end of the custom one, `CallWindowProc` to the old one. It was quite ugly hacker stuff... and possibly no longer supported.